# Why is mobile version of the site missing flag comment functionality

Tags: feature-request, flags, mobile-web, comment-flags

From time to time I log into Stack Overflow via my smartphone (nexus 1, android 2.3.6 I know it's old but it serves me well). I miss some of the functionality of the website in its mobile version especially the ability to flag comments. I know I can flag questions and answers but I don't understand why flagging a comment is not possible. Any good reason for this?

Comment: you can search on the mobile site by expanding the top bar

Comment: Instead, I switch to full site, present in the bottom of the site.

Comment: @Bala I prefer the mobile site when I'm on my 360x640 touchscreen with crappy CPU. The full site takes ages to run its javascript

Comment: Flagging amd seeing vote breakdowns are the number 1 and 2 reasons I change to desktop mode

Comment: @RichardTingle I don't get vote breakdowns on my phone either way :-( I don't have 1k meta rep and mobile Opera's support of userscripts is... bad.

Comment: and even the `share` functionality :(

Comment: @psubsee for me I'm talking about comment flags

Comment: [Here you go](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zPGXb.png). (Ashamed about the typo...)

Comment: @RichardTingle for comment flag, you have to zoom that area and click it.

Comment: @Bala I attempted to zoom into your comment on mobile mode and flag it (as what I'm going to call a test) but on clicking the area under the upvote there was no response

Comment: @RichardTingle really sorry, ya not working and i mentioned it for full site using mobile and also i noticed now @ notation also not working in mobile mode, really sorry.